# Listen for Bluetooth peripheral button events

Tags: c#, bluetooth, 32feet

I have a Bluetooth monopod (aka "Selfie Stick") and I want to be able to see the button click events in a console window. So far I have this code to list the bluetooth devices connected to my laptop:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cli = new BluetoothClient();
    var peers = cli.DiscoverDevices();
    foreach (var peer in peers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(peer.DeviceAddress.ToString() + "\t" + peer.DeviceName);
    }
    var device = peers[0];
    var service = device.InstalledServices[0];
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I am using the [32feet.net](https://32feet.codeplex.com/) library.
How would I go about listening for the button click and writing the

Is this even achievable with 32feet (or any C# bluetooth library?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Bluetooth monopod is likely using a Bluetooth HID connection (keyboard). On iOS the Volume Up button will trigger a camera picture, not sure about Android. Your C# application should be listening to general incoming keyboard activity. It doesn't matter which keyboard (Bluetooth or built-in) is sending HID key presses. I don't think you need 32feet library.